# input_iterator asking for a template name

Tags: c++, iterator

I have been trying to compile the below piece of code but get an error shown. I am not sure what template name it is expecting. Am new to this and this is a very old code which is getting compiled on a new g++ compiler. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance, appreciate it.

Error:

```
./dir.h:12: error: expected template-name before â<â token
./dir.h:12: error: expected â{â before â<â token
./dir.h:12: error: expected unqualified-id before â<â token
make: *** exit code 1 making Life.o
```

Code:

```
#if !defined(DIRECTORY_H)
#define DIRECTORY_H
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//using std::input_iterator;

using std::string;

    struct dir_it_rep;
    class dir_it : public input_iterator<string,int>  //<------- Line 12
    {
    public:
      dir_it();                              // "past the end" ctor
      explicit dir_it(string const &);       // the "normal" ctor
      dir_it(dir_it const &it);
      ~dir_it();

      dir_it &operator= (dir_it const &it);

      string operator* () const { return i_value; }

      dir_it &operator++ ();
      dir_it operator++ (int) { dir_it rc (*this); operator++(); return rc; }

      bool operator== (dir_it const &it) const;
      bool operator!= (dir_it const &it) const { return !operator== (it); }

    private:
      dir_it_rep *i_rep;    // representation for the next value
      string     i_value;   // the current value
    };




#endif /* DIRECTORY_H */
```

Comment: `input_iterator`? Maybe you mean `insert_iterator`?

Comment: There is no `std::input_iterator`. Maybe someone modified the `iterator` header in order to compile this (which hopefully didn't happen). Maybe you mean `std::iterator`?

Comment: First: There is not `std::input_iterator`. Second: Iterators are dessigned through concepts, not through a class hierarchy. The Standard Library provides the base class [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) to provide a common compatible interface for iterators (In other words, to simplify things). **But the different types of iterators are just concepts which your own iterator implementation have to fullfill to belong into a specific iterator category**. Check this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Comment: Old code? Maybe `input_iterator` then is from SGI's STL, see [their documentation of `input_iterator`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/input_iterator.html). It didn't make it in the C++ Standard, though. Try to replace it with `std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, string>` (header `<iterator>`).

Answer (score 0):

First: There is not `std::input_iterator`. Second: Iterators are dessigned through concepts, not through a class hierarchy.
 The Standard Library provides the base class [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) to provide a common compatible interface for iterators (In other words, to simplify things). **But the different types of iterators are just concepts which your own iterator implementation have to meet to belong into a specific iterator category**.

In other words: The different iterator categories (Forward iterator, Input iterator, Bidirectional Iterator) are just class concepts. That is, for example, if you want to write a class that you want to be considered a forward iterator, your class must have to meet a list of conditions/features:

- Your class must be [default constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible).
- Your class must meet the [InputIterator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) too.
- Must overload the preincrement and postincrement operators meeting a set of specified behaviors (Read the documentation).
- The class must be dereferenzable, that is, overloads `operator*()`.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) is the documentation which explains the requeriments of the `ForwardIterator` concept.

Also, the Standard Library provides a set of classes which act as "tags" to determine the category of an iterator class (Because iterators are not a class hierarchy, we need an indirect form to be sure about the category of the iterator. Note that in the common cases this is not worrying, because we use iterators in a generic way): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Read the documentation about [the iterators library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). It provides a good explanation about iteratrs, its dessign, and its concepts.